# How to check if user is presence in asp.net aplicattion using Matrix Xmpp SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, matrix, xmpp

i am looking for any ideas how to implement of checking if user is connected to Xmpp Server.

Whole procedure look like contact list in client i load a list of contacts and i want to check every single user and add to him info of his presence (online / away)

i have read ag-software tutorial 
http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/matrix-developer-tutorial/#glosary-presence
 but did't find any good explained solution, all other internet resources are blank too.

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

By default consider all your contacts as offline. For all your online contacts you get the OnPresence event. One event per contact.